# Statement with no effect -Wunused-value

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I can't for the life of me figure out why it thinks this wouldn't have an effect:

```
int neededSize = size + ROW_SIZE;
int offset = neededSize % MIN_BLOCK_SIZE;
int padding = 0;
if(offset != 0){
    padding = MIN_BLOCK_SIZE + offset;amount of padding that we need
}
int requiredSize = neededSize + padding;
```

The error is as follows:

```
src/sfmm.c:63:34: error: statement with no effect [-Werror=unused-value]
     padding = MIN_BLOCK_SIZE - offset;
```

MIN_BLOCK_SIZE definition in included .h file:

```
#define MIN_BLOCK_SIZE 64;
```

My text editor is showing the error on the minus sign in that particular line.

Let me know if you need to see any more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined `MIN_BLOCK_SIZE` with a final semi-colon:

```
#define MIN_BLOCK_SIZE 64;
```

Because of your #define, the expression is:

```
padding = 64; + offset;
```

So, it is two separate statements.

- The first statement assigns `64` to variable `padding`.
- The second statement is just `+offset;`, and does not have any effect.
  It just evaluates to a value that is discarded.

The error message is correct.

I believe you ***meant*** to define

```
#define MIN_BLOCK_SIZE 64  // Without the final semi-colon.
```

Then the expression would be:

```
padding = 64 + offset;
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew it had to be some really simple mistake. Macros are very weird to get used to. Will accept when the timer lets me